# Free Standby Memory without a Reboot

Tags: memory, windows-10, hyper-v, standby

Does anyone know of a way to clear standby memory without a reboot?

I can't launch my HyperV VMs after doing other tasks in Win 10 after running tasks due to the lack of free memory.  I would have enough memory (free + standby), but HyperV doesn't seem to count the standby RAM as available for the VM.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Run [ProcessHacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/) as admin, click on View->System Information->Memory->Memory Lists->More and select here `Empty Standby List` under the entry empty:

[image]

Comment: @John nice to hear this.

Comment: @Alpha3031 RAMMap is now updated for Win10, so you can undelete the answer now.

Comment: Yeah, let's remove useful quick answers from the internet *or* you could have just mentioned RAMMap was updated which I just tested and it *also* works.

Answer (score 3):

You can use RAMMap v1.5 (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ff700229)

1. Download RamMap from Microsoft Windows Sysinternals.
2. Run RamMap (installation is not required).
3. Wait until UseCounts shows the memory map.
4. On the Menu Strip, indentify the Empty menu item. Click on it and choose Empty Standby List from the dropdown menu.
5. Press F5 to
   update the Use Counts tab or check the memory tab on the Windows
   Resource Monitor to check that the Standby Memory has been released.

Source: https://support.software.dell.com/appassure/kb/118393

Comment: Empty Standby List wasn't enough for me today, but after using RamMap to empty all five options (Working Sets, System Working Set, Modified Page List, Standby List, and Priority 0 Standby List), I was able to start my virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

I may be too late, but since no one has mentioned Empty Standby List command line, I thought of including it here.

I am using Empty Standby List  https://wj32.org/wp/software/empty-standby-list/

Then I created a batch file which will automatically clear the standby memory every 5 minutes = 300 seconds (which can be adjusted to your own liking). I will let this run on the background (run as admin as well). This works with my Windows 7 Professional x64.

```
:loop
echo Clearing...
EmptyStandbyList.exe standbylist
timeout 300
cls
goto loop
```

EDIT: Removed unnecessary " that was causing batch file to fail